# Autorestart of VM in Virtual Box

Tags: boot, virtualbox, autostart

I am unable to autostart my Ubuntu 20.04 VM. I followed the instructions on the VirtualBox website. The VM boots without issue if I use the VirtualBox app.

Any ideas on how to proceed? I also have this question posted in the VBox forum.

From VBoxManage showvminfo:

- Autostart Enabled: enabled
- Autostart Delay: 0

Here is my VBox log file entry

```
00:00:04.931179 VirtualBox VM 6.1.22 r144080 darwin.amd64 (Apr 28 2021 18:46:07) release log
00:00:04.931194 Log opened 2021-06-13T14:53:40.107492000Z
00:00:04.931195 Build Type: release
00:00:04.931204 OS Product: Darwin
00:00:04.931209 OS Release: 20.4.0
00:00:04.931213 OS Version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Fri Mar 5 01:14:14 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.1~3/RELEASE_X86_64
00:00:04.931279 DMI Product Name: iMac17,1
00:00:04.931309 DMI Product Version: 1.0
00:00:04.931312 Firmware type: failed - VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED
00:00:04.931319 Host RAM: 24576MB (24.0GB) total, 22485MB (21.9GB) available
00:00:04.931321 Executable: /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxHeadless
00:00:04.931321 Process ID: 1031
00:00:04.931322 Package type: DARWIN_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:04.933532 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:04.933548 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack (Version: 6.1.22 r144080; VRDE Module: VBoxVRDP)
00:00:04.934377 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:08.478622 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:08.480421 Power up failed (vrc=VINF_SUCCESS, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))
```

Comment: The error seen at `08.480421` is generally seen when the VM specified in the auto start config file doesn’t exist, which is usually the result of a typo.

Comment: Thank You. I cannot find where the VM is specified. I setup the configs to autostart VMs and it looks like it is using the metadata in the VM specifically "Autostart Enabled: enabled".  

I conclude this after manually running the script in /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.vboxautostart.plist. 

VBoxAutostart --start --verbose --config /etc/vbox/autostart.cfg. 

I get "The machine 'Ubuntu_Desktop_20.04 MMP Mail' is already locked by a session (or being locked or unlocked)". 

This seems to imply that the correct VM is trying to start.